# replace multiple words - python

Tags: python

There can be an input `"some word"`.

I want to replace this input with `"<strong>some</strong> <strong>word</strong>"` in some other text which contains this input

I am trying with this code:

```
input = "some word".split()
pattern = re.compile('(%s)' % input, re.IGNORECASE)
result = pattern.sub(r'<strong>\1</strong>',text)
```

but it is failing and i know why: i am wondering how to pass all elements of list `input` to `compile()` so that `(%s)` can catch each of them.

appreciate any help

Comment: You shouldn't use `input` as variable name - it's a built-in function...

Comment: @Roberto sure, done just for understanding here ;) thanks though

Comment: @Roberto that was good point np  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right approach, since you're already splitting the list, is to surround each item of the list directly (never using a regex at all):

```
sterm = "some word".split()
result = " ".join("<strong>%s</strong>" % w for w in sterm)
```

---

In case you're wondering, the pattern you were looking for was:

```
pattern = re.compile('(%s)' % '|'.join(sterm), re.IGNORECASE)
```

This works on your string because the regular expression would become

```
(some|word)
```

which means "matches `some` or matches `word`".

However, this is not a good approach as it does not work for all strings. For example, consider cases where one word contains another, such as

```
a banana and an apple
```

which becomes:

```
<strong>a</strong> <strong>banana</strong> <strong>a</strong>nd <strong>a</strong>n <strong>a</strong>pple
```

Comment: thanks David. very nice didnot know that. how cool is python!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're wanting to search for multiple words - this word *or* that word.  Which means you need to separate your searches by |, like the script below:

```
import re

text = "some word many other words"
input = '|'.join('some word'.split())
pattern = re.compile('(%s)' % input, flags=0)
print pattern.sub(r'<strong>\1</strong>',text)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure if I know what you're asking but if you want to pass all the elements of input in as parameters in the compile function call, you can just use *input instead of input. * will split the list into its elements. As an alternative, could't you just try joining the list with   **and adding  at the beginning and**  at the end?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use the join operator with a list comprehension to create the intended result.

```
text = "some word many other words".split()
result = ' '.join(['<strong>'+i+'</strong>' for i in text])
```